# Django creates two model instances instead of one

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-managers

I'm trying to learn some django basics following one turorial from youtube and have got strange result when I try to create some model instances using forms. Django implicitly creates two duplicate instances.
This is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ProductModelForm
from .models import Product

def create(request):
    form = ProductModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        data = form.cleaned_data
        Product.objects.create(title_text=data.get("title_text"))
        obj.save()
    return render(request, "test_app/create.html", {"form": form})
```

Form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Product

class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            "title_text",
        ]
```

And a template:

```
{% block content %}

<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Save Model</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
```

this create one instance first.

```
obj.save()
```

And then this creates another instance.

Comment: `obj = form.save(commit=False` and `obj.save()` create ONE object together. The second object is being created by `Product.objects.create(title_text=data.get("title_text"))`

Comment: Thanks. Hope to see you again.

Comment: @AlexStelmakh Yeah, this is no the correct answer. The one accepted should be the one from DilIsPickle

Comment: @gdef_ This is a first one and it do the job for me. Maybe not so comprehensive, but anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This creates an object

```
obj = form.save(commit=False) 
obj.save()
```

And this creates an object

```
data = form.cleaned_data
Product.objects.create(title_text=data.get("title_text"))
```

Try this

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
data = form.cleaned_data
obj.title_text = data.get("title_Text")
obj.save()
```